# PHP/Mysql User Management with custom directories question

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Yet another PHP/MySQL user management question. It's for an image editor, and so each user should have their own "space" i.e. user directory (USERDIR) upon signing up, and anything under that directory should be accessible to the relevant user only. Fairly simple step up but I can't seem to find the right keywords to search for a tutorial.

The way I was thinking of implementing it is having a "USERDIR" column in the MySQL db along side "USERID" and "PASSWORD" (md5 hashed) (although I understand USERDIR is a redundant key if USERIDs are also unique - is this an issue to be worried about? i.e. I could just assign the USERID as the directory name instead of generating a unique random directory name). How do I then "check" whether the user has the privileges to access their directory (i.e. how do I code it to check the sessionID/cookie checking to stop another user from going to mysite.com/USERID or mysite.com/USERDIR). I appreciate this is really basic and repetitive for some of you but I can't seem to find the relevant tutorials anywhere! Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, just use UserID based storage of the image files. But, make sure you wrap your request for a userdir location in a function call in case you need to change it to deal with directory file limits.  for instance assume $imageName is the name of the image you are trying to store or retrieve,.

```
$userDir = getUserDir($userID);
$imgLink = 'http://' .$hostname .'/' . $userDir . '/' . $imgName;

function getUserDir($userID)
{
    return 'images/' . $userID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I won't hardcode the image paths. If you could also possibly advise on the SWF Editor security bypass issue (See below Niggles comment) I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also serve up the image via PHP to ensure that there are no visible paths to the image in a web page e.g

```
$imagepath= 'some-input-file.jpg';
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($image, '', 90);
```

Mind you, this doesn't stop other people viewing the image if they WERE to find the real link - for that you may need to use .htaccess

Comment: Thank you, yes I intend the actual link to the edited images to be hotlinkable, I just don't want the Flash editor (which will load the images) to be accessible to non-privilleged users. The problem however, is that the editor is in Flash so I guess I need to do the USERID checking with Flash as if someone gets the link to the SWF they could bypass all the php security? Or is there a simpler way to use mod_rewrite to disable directly accessing the swf editor?

Comment: I would do 2 things - get Flash to send out a $_POST request expecting a certain response to verify the user is logged in. This is not foolproof though. Before you actually do the move_uploaded_file (which you need to do at some stage yes) you should check they have permission to upload and also set the upload path. This way even if someone gets to the Flash, without the right credentials, nothing can ever be uploaded.